# Reading nested json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to handle nested JSON in Angular/ionic app. I am getting this json after converting a XML dataset to json. Returned Json is as following

```
     {
       "Root": {
        "row": [
          {
            "@CompleteURL": "x.jpg"
          },
          {
            "@CompleteURL": "x.jpg"
          },
          {
            "@CompleteURL": "x.jpg"
          }
        ]
       }
     }
```

I need to get values for @CompleteURL for every row. However, I have tried everything after

```
    $scope.DealImages.Root.row[i]
```

but I am not getting values against CompleteURL!

This is the SQL which is generating XML

```
    SELECT CompleteURL FROM Images WHERE ReferenceID=d.DealID FOR XML RAW, ROOT('Root')
```

And this is how WebAPI is converting XML to json

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Result.Count; i++)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(Result[i].ImageURL);
        Result[i].ImageURL = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
    }
```

This is how I am reading this javascript

```
    $scope.DealImages = JSON.parse(DealDetailAttributes.ImageURL);
```

This part is doing well as I can get json. In debugger's json tree, I can also see values so this part should be OK. I am not able to get up to final value though.

This is the codepen link http://codepen.io/Utsavv/pen/zvWwrR?editors=001

Comment: Could you add the code with which you inspect `$scope.DealImages.Root.row[i]` ?

Comment: Edited question with details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the following line, which was only visible in the codepen:

```
alert(x.row[1].CompleteURL);
```

1. `x` does not have a `row` property, but a `Root` property: it should be inserted in the hierarchy.
2. the final `CompleteURL` property does not exist; it needs to be `@CompleteURL`. Since that cannot be written in dot notation, you need bracket notation.

So your line should read:

```
alert(x.Root.row[1]["@CompleteURL"]);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I bind it with ng repeat of angular?

Comment: I never worked with angular, but from te documentation, I guess it would be something like this:     `<div ng-repeat="el in x.Root.row track by $index"> {{el["@CompleteURL"]}} </div>` but again I have not used angular.